# Solr create a new field based on existing field in the same document

Tags: solr

I want to index a new field based on an existing field in all the documents in Solr. For example, I have a field called onBoardDate_string which is currently indexed as a String in Solr. For every document, the field is indexed in the following format "dd/MM/yyyy". Now , I want to create a new field onBoardDate_date in all the documents which have the onBoardDate_string field. How can I do it?

**NOTE: I cannot pull the data from DB. Hence need to use the existing documents in Solr.**

Comment: Are all your fields stored? i.e. can you retrieve the complete document - all fields - after querying for the document in Solr? In general, what you're asking about will require reindexing those documents that should have the new field, and for that to work properly you'll usually have to have the complete content of those documents available.

Comment: Yes. All the fields are stored.

Comment: Make a request to `/export` to retrieve all the document ids present, then for each id, issue an atomic update that adds the new field: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/updating-parts-of-documents.html

Comment: Can we do an atomic update using CSV? I tried to update, but it adds the new field in the document but remove all other fields.

Comment: No, not that I know of. You have to send an update message for each document manually. You could export the whole result set as CSV, add the field to the csv-file and then upload the new versions of all the documents.